# Check if variable is either a couple types? (str or list)

Tags: python, if-statement, types, boolean

I know if i want to check for example if variable x is a str I will do

```
if type(x) is str:
```

but how can I check if x is either a string or list? So I can do this without adding another if branch

```
if type(x) is (str, list):
     pass
else:
     raise SomeError
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type(x) in (str, list)
```

or

```
isinstance(x, (str, list))
```

The two are not semantically identical. Read on the `isinstance()` function in the docs.

Comment: `isinstance()` is usually preferred (but not always).

Comment: Right, depending on which semantic you want. :) But most of the time you want `isinstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if isinstance(x, list) or isinstance(x, list):
```

Or for a number of different types

```
if any(isinstance(x, i) for i in [list, tuple, string]):
```

Or if you'd like to see if it is any type of iterable

```
if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
```

Comment: I think `isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)` is more Pythonic than `hasattr(x, '__iter__')`. -- You can pass a tuple as the second argument to `isinstance()`

Comment: @NiklasR They're not exactly equivalent. If I make a silly class like `class Test(object): def __iter__(self): return []`, `hasattr(Test, '__iter__')`would return True, and `isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)` would return False. Depends on how you want to treat malformed classes like my Test class.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I can't confirm that behaviour, for me `isinstance(Test(), collections.Iterable)` returns True. http://ideone.com/YbEbzA

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` keyword similar below:

```
if type(x) in (str, list):
```

Or use `isinstance` builtin function:

```
if isinstance(x, (str, list)):
```